# CI/CD Pipeline config for GitLab to publish ASP.NET Core 6 web app in docker container

Tags: docker, .net-core, gitlab

I need to start by saying that I am a beginner with CI/CD and with Gitlab. That being said, I have managed to cobble together (using examples from the web) this "almost" working pipeline configuration:

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0

variables:
  OBJECTS_DIRECTORY: 'obj'
  NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY: '.nuget'
  SOURCE_CODE_PATH: '*/*/'
  TAG_LATEST: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:latest
  TAG_COMMIT: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - docker
  - deploy

cache:
  key: "$CI_JOB_STAGE-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
  paths:
    - '$SOURCE_CODE_PATH$OBJECTS_DIRECTORY/project.assets.json'
    - '$SOURCE_CODE_PATH$OBJECTS_DIRECTORY/*.csproj.nuget.*'
    - '$NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY'
  policy: pull-push

before_script:
  - 'dotnet restore --packages $NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY'

build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - 'dotnet build --no-restore'

tests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - 'dotnet test --no-restore'

docker:
  stage: docker
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:18.09.7-dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  only:
    - main
before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install docker -y
  script:
    - docker login -u "gitlab-ci-token" -p "$CI_JOB_TOKEN" $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build --tag "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA" --tag "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest"

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: alpine:latest
  services:
  - docker:dind

  script:
  - chmod og= $ID_RSA
  - apk update && apk add openssh-client
  - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY"
  - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker pull $TAG_COMMIT"
  - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker container rm -f atlas-portal-2.0 || true"
  - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker run -d -p 80:80 --name atlas-portal-2.0 $TAG_COMMIT"
  environment: 
    name: production
  only:
  - main
```

When I run this pipeline, it successfully gets to the “docker” stage where I hope to build and store the docker image in the gitlab container registry. Instead I get the following error:

> "/bin/bash: line 149: docker: command not found"

I know that somehow I need to “install” docker in the docker image that is going to be building the docker image to store in gitlab, but I am not sure how to go about doing that.

And once I get past this “docker” stage I feel confident that the “deploy” stage is going to fail too. I am a newbie...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `docker` job should look like this instead:

```
docker:
  stage: docker
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  only:
    - main
before_script:
    - docker login -u "gitlab-ci-token" -p "$CI_JOB_TOKEN" $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - docker build --tag "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA" --tag "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest"
```

As you're already using an image that has `docker` installed, there is no need to run `apt-get update && apt-get install docker -y`, just run the command and that will make up for it.

Also another piece of advice, it'd be best for you to define the `image` value for each job unless you will use the same for all of them. So the one you have defined at the top of the file to use `dotnet` would be better placed at `build` and `tests` jobs. If you don't want to repeat code you can use variables to reuse the value, e.g:

```
variables:
    DOTNET_IMAGE: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0

...

build:
    image: $DOTNET_IMAGE

...

tests:
    image: $DOTNET_IMAGE
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying your suggestion now.  :)

Comment: WOW! That worked!  Now I just need to figure out the "deploy" portion

Comment: Happy to hear the solution worked for you. If you need help with the deployment step, feel free to create a new question and share it here and I'll try to help as well!

Comment: will do! I will post a link soon :)